# IonViewWillEnter doesn't get Triggered

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

So I have 3 pages (2 normal view pages and 1 modal page). One of the 2 normal view pages (page A) opens the modal page, and the modal page calls the other normal view page (B).

There’s a button in B that updates the database and goes back supposedly to A. I need to make A be updated inline with the updated database such that after pressing the button in B, it calls again my APIs deployed in a web server. I am aware of ion view page lifecycle, and I think IonViewWillEnter/IonViewDidEnter might help me. However, upon using either of the two, it doesn’t get triggered after popping from B.

Any help?

Here are the snippets of the typescript files.

**Normal View Page (A) that calls the modal. Method loadData is the call to API service**

```
ionViewWillEnter() {
this.loadData();
}

loadData(){
this.user = this.dataService.getParamData();
this.hcf_id = this.user.hcfId;
this.sub = this.roomService.getAllRooms(this.hcf_id).subscribe(e => {
this.rooms = e;
});
this.sub2 = this.roomService.getAllRoomByType(this.hcf_id, 1).subscribe(e => {
this.commonRooms = e;
});
this.sub3 = this.roomService.getAllRoomByType(this.hcf_id, 2).subscribe(e => {
this.functionalRooms = e;
});
}

async showDetails(response: Room){
const modal = await this.modalController.create({
component: ModalPage,
componentProps: {
room: response
}
});
modal.present();
}
```

**Modal page that calls normal view page B**

```
closeModal(){
this.modalController.dismiss();
}

editLPGRP(room_id: Number){
this.dataService.pushTempData(this.lpgrpGen);
this.navCtrl.navigateForward(‘lpgrfgen’);
this.closeModal();
}
```

**Normal View Page B which has a button to update the database thru API and pops back to A**

```
calculateFunctionality(){
this.lpgrpAssessmentService.updateGenAssessment(this.lpgrpGen).subscribe();
this.navCtrl.pop();
}
else{
alert(“Please finish assessing all the elements before calculating functionality!”);
}
}
```

Comment: Try angular ngOnInit()

Comment: Doesn't get triggered as well.